# yii2 checkbox is not showing but label is visible

Tags: checkbox, yii2

```
     <?= $form->field($model, 'term_condition')->checkbox(); ?>
```

It is not showing the checkbox but it shows the label.

and I looked into the generated html and that is also fine.here is the generated html.

```
<div class="form-group field-dynamicmodel-term_condition">
<input type="hidden" name="DynamicModel[term_condition]" value="0"><label> . 
    <input type="checkbox" id="dynamicmodel-term_condition" 
     name="DynamicModel[term_condition]" value="1"> Term Condition</label>
<div class="help-block"></div>
```

Comment: It could be the `CSS`, the `HTML` that you posted displays a checkbox for me. Did you try the inspector to see if the element is there?

Comment: @Dksingh is the any templating you apply to form fields in Active form or globally? Why generated `html` provided by you include hidden input in `<div class="form-group">`? the right syntax for this will be different. And label can not include checkbox, it should be generated before to checkbox apear.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, in my case I could solve it with css:

```
.form-group input[type="checkbox"]{ display: block;}
```

For a reason when the input is rendered, the display property is none

Answer (score -1):

There are options missing.

As stated in the [docs](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-activefield#checkbox()-detail) the method is defined as

```
public $this checkbox ( $options = [], $enclosedByLabel = true )
```

With the default - an empty `$options` array - there is nothing to display.

So just specify some options and the checkbox will be displayed:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'term_condition')->checkbox([
    "0" => "Option 1", 
    "1" => "Option 2"
]); ?>
```

Comment: was not me, but you don't have to specify values in options if is not checkboxlist or radio

Comment: @WeSee You could try to read documentation you've lined, it should explain why this answer is incorrect.